# Chrome dev tools display of printing array of jQuery objects to the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I've the the following sample code with a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UbN5j/)
JS

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
                var bKids = $('.contained').find('button');
                var pKids = $('.contained').find('p');
                console.log('this is from bKids: ' + bKids.length)
                console.log('this is from pkids: ' + pKids.length);
                console.log(bKids);
                console.log(pKids);
            });
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="contained">
        <p>first child p tag</p>
        <p>second child p tag</p>
        <p>third child p tag</p>
        </div></div>
```

When I open up Chrome dev tools (and I assume other dev tools e.g. Firebug) if I inspect the bKids object I see that there are no selectors and the first property in the object is prevObject.  In the pKids object, we have an array of p tags inside a div, and before the prevObject property there are three p's.  What part of the jQuery object is this exactly, and if I wanted to refer to it by a property name, i.e. context, selector, etc.  how could I do it?

Comment: "jQuery object is this" What is "this" referring to?

Comment: this = the property that precedes prevObject in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties you're looking at/for, I gather, are the *numbered properties* containing the elements you're looking to select with the jQuery object - as in, any `button` elements for `bKids` and any `p` elements in `pKids`.

The current elements of a jQuery object can be accessed via the object's `.get()` method:

```
pKids.get()
```

will return an array of `HTMLElement` objects (your `p` elements). You can use `pKids.get(n)` to retrieve just one of these elements by array index. You could also access a single `HTMLElement` by its index as `pKids[n]`